# How to illustrate schematically (animated) solutions of a system of $3$-variable equations by increasing one of the variables with step $0.01$?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, animation, parametric-functions

Following my previous question
[here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246767/how-to-plot-solutions-of-a-system-of-equations-by-changing-colours-when-one-of-t), I am looking an alternative way to solve this problem (the method was not applicable to more complicated situations). I have a system of two 3-variable equations $Eqs=\{f(x,y,z)=0\;,\;g(x,y,z)=0\}$ where the domain of variables are
$$5.6 < x < 2 \pi \\
- \frac{15}{100} < y < 0\\
0 < z < \pi$$

**These are what I need:**

- 1. First, by changing the variable $z$ by step $0.01$, i.e. for all the values $z=\{0,\;0.01,...,1.49,\;1.50\}$, find the points $(x,y)$ which solve this system of equation.
- 2. Then illustrate these points in a 2D plot of $x,y$ as a continuous curve (joining the points $(x,y)$ from the first step).
- 3. Show the behaviour of $z$ in this 2D plot $(x,y)$ by changing the colours, I mean to show that by changing $z$ from $0$ to $\pi$, the curve's colour changes from Red to Blue for example. (something like the attached plot)

[image]

- 4. If possible, show the behaviour of $z$ in this 2D plot $(x,y)$ as an animated gif, I mean the curve in $x-y$ plain starts at $(x,y)=(2\pi,0)$ with $z=0$ and moves toward the last point $(x,y)=(5.6,0)$ with $z=\pi$. (something like the attached gif (showing the value of $z$), it is not related to this equation, I took it from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126975/plot-and-animate-a-parametric-circle-with-a-cycloid/126979#126979) )

[image]

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := 
 9 E^(373 y/50) - 3 E^(4 y) Cos[(173 x)/50] + E^(173 y/50) Cos[4 x] - 
   2 E^(2 y) Cos[(273 x)/50] - 3 Cos[(373 x)/50] + 
   8 E^(2 y) Cos[(273 x)/50] Cos[z] - 
   2 E^(273 y/50) Cos[2 x] (1 + 4 Cos[z]) ;


g[x_, y_, z_] := -2 E^(273 y/50) (1 + 4 Cos[z]) Sin[2 x] - 
   3 E^(4 y) Sin[(173 x)/50] + E^(173 y/50) Sin[4 x] - 
   2 E^(2 y) Sin[(273 x)/50] + 8 E^(2 y) Cos[z] Sin[(273 x)/50] - 
   3 Sin[(373 x)/50] ;


Eqs:={  f[x,y,z]==0 , g[x,y,z]==0  }


5.66 < x < 2 π
-0.15 < y < 0
0 < z < π
```

I am not familiar with programming in Mathematica, I am only able to do some simple calculations like using `FindRoot` to find the position of $(x,y)$, but I do not know what to do after that. I appreciate any comments and answers.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take `NMinimize`(very robust solver)  to solve these two equations

```
s[z_?NumericQ] := {x, y, z} /. 
NMinimize[ {f[x, y, z]^2 + g[x, y, z]^2,5.66 < x < 2 Pi, -15/100 < y < 0}, {x, y} ][[2]]
```

Function `s[z]` returns the solution `{x[z],y[z],z}`

Calculate solution for `0<z<Pi`

```
xyz = Table[s[z], {z, 0, Pi , Pi/50}];
Graphics3D[{Red, Point[xyz]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can we do something about the third and fourth bullet points in the question?

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_, z_] := 
  9 E^(373 y/50) - 3 E^(4 y) Cos[(173 x)/50] + E^(173 y/50) Cos[4 x] - 
   2 E^(2 y) Cos[(273 x)/50] - 3 Cos[(373 x)/50] + 
   8 E^(2 y) Cos[(273 x)/50] Cos[z] - 2 E^(273 y/50) Cos[2 x] (1 + 4 Cos[z]);
g[x_, y_, z_] := -2 E^(273 y/50) (1 + 4 Cos[z]) Sin[2 x] - 
   3 E^(4 y) Sin[(173 x)/50] + E^(173 y/50) Sin[4 x] - 
   2 E^(2 y) Sin[(273 x)/50] + 8 E^(2 y) Cos[z] Sin[(273 x)/50] - 
   3 Sin[(373 x)/50];

cp3d = ContourPlot3D[
   {f[x, y, z] == 0, g[x, y, z] == 0},
   {x, 5.66, 2 π}, {y, -0.15, 0}, {z, 0, π},
   WorkingPrecision -> 15,
   AxesLabel ->
    (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}),
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8],
   PlotLegends -> {f, g}];
```

Following Ulrich Neumann's recommendation to use [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html)

```
s[z_?NumericQ] := {x, y, z} /. 
  NMinimize[{f[x, y, z]^2 + g[x, y, z]^2, 
     566/100 < x < 2 Pi, -15/100 < y < 0}, {x, y}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 15][[2]]

data3d = Table[s[z], {z, 0, Pi, 1/100}];

Legended[
 Show[cp3d,
  ListLinePlot3D[data3d,
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]],
 LineLegend[{Red}, {"f\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]g"}]]
```

[image]

Use [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) to define  `z` as a function of `x`

```
zfx = Interpolation[DeleteDuplicatesBy[data3d[[All, {1, 3}]], First]];
```

The static plot with "mile markers" is

```
Legended[
 ListLinePlot[Most /@ data3d,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel ->
   (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y},
    ColorData["Rainbow"][zfx[x]/Pi]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[3],
    Tooltip[Point[Most@#],
       StringForm["z\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``", N@#[[3]]]] & /@
     Select[data3d, IntegerQ[2 #[[3]]] &]},
  PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["``=\[ThinSpace]0, ``=\[ThinSpace]0",
     HoldForm[f[x, y, z]],
     HoldForm[g[x, y, z]]], 14, Bold]],
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, Pi}},
  LegendLabel -> Style[z, 14, Bold]]]
```

[image]

For a dynamic plot use either [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) or [`Animate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Legended[
  ListLinePlot[Most /@ data3d,
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel ->
    (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y},
     ColorData["Rainbow"][zfx[x]/Pi]],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4],
     Point[Most@s[zz]]},
   PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["``=\[ThinSpace]0, ``=\[ThinSpace]0",
      HoldForm[f[x, y, z]],
      HoldForm[g[x, y, z]]], 14, Bold]],
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, Pi}},
   LegendLabel -> Style[z, 14, Bold]]],
 {{zz, 0, z}, 0, Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> {"Open","Labeled"}}]
```

[image]

To make a `GIF` make a `Table` of the desired frames

```
frames = Table[
   Manipulate[
    Legended[
     ListLinePlot[Most /@ data3d,
      Frame -> True,
      FrameLabel ->
       (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
      ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y},
        ColorData["Rainbow"][zfx[x]/Pi]],
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
      Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4],
        Point[Most@s[zz]]},
      PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["``=\[ThinSpace]0, ``=\[ThinSpace]0",
         HoldForm[f[x, y, z]],
         HoldForm[g[x, y, z]]], 14, Bold]],
     BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, Pi}},
      LegendLabel -> Style[z, 14, Bold]]],
    {{zz, init, z}, 0, Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> {"Open", "Labeled"}}],
   {init, 0, Pi, Pi/10.}]; (* change step size as required *)

Export["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/manipulate.gif",
 frames]

(* "/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/manipulate.gif" *)
```

Comment: Thank you again for this answer and also the previous one. Is it possible to express your last plot as an animated gif that shows the exact numeric value of $z$ as the black point moves through the curve? (like the gif I have attached to the text). Manipulate is useful to see the behaviour, but I need an animation.